# laravel collection groupBy() / include empty results

Tags: laravel, collections, laravel-6.2

For a chart API I would need to provide the count of registered users per day.

```
//fetch all created_at dates of users from the last week
$signUpsLastWeek = User::whereDate('created_at', '>=', now()->subDays(7))->select('created_at')->get();

//group them now by date now, using collection operations
dd($signUpsLastWeek->groupBy(function($item) {
    return $item->created_at->format('m.d');
}));

//now manipulate the collection a bit, so we get the date with the amount of new registered users
$signUpsLastWeek->mapWithKeys(function ($userGroup, $key) {
    return [$key => $userGroup->count()];
})
```

Returns:

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#774 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    "01.19" => 4
  ]
}
```

This works fine, a question is left.

In the example code above there are 0 new signups on the other days, meaning the collection should look something like:

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#774 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    "01.25" => 0,
    "01.24" => 0,
    "01.23" => 0,
    "01.22" => 0,
    "01.20" => 0,
    "01.19" => 4,
    ...,
  ]
}
```

Any idea how to include the 0 amounts too?

Comment: from which day to display?

Comment: starting from `today()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `CarbonPeriod` to create the calendar and set the default count 0 for every date.

And then reset the value from your users' count:

```php
$start_date = explode(' ', User::whereDate('created_at', '>=', now()->subDays(7))->min('created_at'))[0];
$end_date = \Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d');
$period = \Carbon\CarbonPeriod::create($start_date, $end_date);

$all_dates = [];
foreach ($period as $date) {
    $all_dates = array_merge($all_dates, [$date->format('m.d') => 0]);
}
$all_dates = array_reverse($all_dates);

collect($all_dates)->mapWithKeys(function($v, $date) use ($signUpsLastWeek) {
                    if (in_array($date, array_keys($signUpsLastWeek))) {
                        return [$date => $signUpsLastWeek[$date]->count()];
                    } else {
                        return [$date => 0];
                    }
                })->all();
```